# Xcode image reset error

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a moving image in an app of mine that works perfectly fine. But when I add an image to the screen with this code every 1 second the moving image resets its position.  Like it's going up, an image gets added, the moving image teleports to where it started and continues moving up.  Heres the code I used to the add the images:

```
UIImageView * trail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 20, 20)];
trail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dust.png"];
[self.view addSubview:trail];
```

I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do with this, but my app works without it. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before.

Comment: Just as a side note: The images I'm adding add perfectly fine.

Comment: I am not seeing a question here. The code you've provided is working fine that's what you are saying in your comment?

Comment: that code is working perfectly fine, but as I said in my question my other image which is moving resets its position to it's initial position whenever I make a new image. Like it's going up then i make a new dust image the image comes back down to where it started even though there is no connection.